# What type of multithreading would be best to learn?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I want to learn multi-threading in C++ but I'm not sure what type would be most useful. The ones I've seen tutorials on are:

- Windows native calls
- OpenMP
- Boost

(I'm sure that there are probably more.)

What is each one's key features and what are they best used for?

Note: I've already done some multi-threading in C# by manually creating the threads, and more complexity of the threading will just make it more fun. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about [TBB](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/)? It is portable and has easy to use parallel template patterns,  concurrent containers, task scheduler and scalable memory allocaturs. TBB will let you manage threads directly, but that is not necessary in most of the cases.

Personally I would stay away from platform specific threads, unless there an urgent need to do something, well, platform specific.

Boost threads is portable and easy to use, but does have neither parallel patterns nor concurrent containers. You would need to manager threads manually, which can get ugly pretty quickly.

PThreads isn't available on Windows and its C. You really want to do multi-threading in C++, not C. RAII mixes well with mutexes and scoped locks.

Another option is PPL in Visual C++ 2010. It is similar to TBB, but as you may guess available for Windows only.

OpenMP is easy to use, but not very flexible. Since you already learned C++, you should  use something more serious, such as TBB or PPL. For some strange reason Visual C++ 2010 doesn't support OpenMP 3. Too bad.

Comment: TBB looks interesting. It works on all brands of chip right? Do you know how efficient it is compared with boost::threads? RAII looks very interesting too. I have a lot of learning/reading todo. think I will pass on PPL though not too keen on 2010. Thanks!  PS i agree with doing the threads in C++, C++ is what i want to learn and when making C++ projects why mix in C?

Answer (score 5):

I'd start with pthreads if you have more of a C background, or Boost Thread if you are accustomed to more idiomatic C++.  Either is reasonably portable and widely used.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be *portable*, learn Posix threads. You know, all thread libraries provide more or less the same set of features, so it's up to you, but Posix will give you the basis.

openMP isn't exactly "multi-threading" as you mean it.

Comment: hmm pthreads look good, the only thing its from C, now my lecture says don't mix C in with C++ becuase its bad (at least with memory management) do you think it would matter?

Comment: You have an interesting definition of "portable" if you consider the most portable option to be the one that doesn't run on 90% of people's PC's. ;) Anyway, in C, pthreads are the de factor standard everywhere except Windows, which has its own threading API. In C++, Boost.Thread  is your best bet (It is portable, it's idiomatic C++, and it's been a strong inspiration for the threading functionality added to the language in C++11.

Comment: @ jalf: thanks, i was thinking that boost would be best from John's answer, know of any good tutorials or example code to get me started on a good oo threading design?

Comment: @QuantumKarl: what does OO have to do with anything? The Boost.Thread docs have some examples of how to use the library. As for how you structure your code? the same way you'd structure any other code.

Comment: @jalf: ok, i didn't know if OO threading would differ, since one of the tutorials i looked at for #include<threads.h> was specifically OO multi-threading so i wasn't sure

Comment: Some people will slap an "OO" label on absolutely anything. Good design is good design. Whether or not it is "OO" is insignificant. And especially in C++, OO is often the wrong way to go. Boost.Thread isn't particularly object-oriented, because that would have made it less generic, slower and less type-safe. That's often how it goes in C++. So in general, ask about *good design*, not *good OO design*. `</rant>`

Comment: @cicada: can you elaborate about why OpenMP isn't multithreading as OP meant it?

Answer (score 1):

WinThreads (Windows) and pthreads (Linux) are POSIX threads and represent probably your best choice to get started.  It is important to learn the distinction between processes and threads, then learn about the various memory access models that are associated with them.  Next, try concurrency approaches like OpenMP and MPI "threads".

There are some basic concepts that will get repeated. Learn them well.